# Animating Smooth Density Histogram

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, animation

I have a large data file (~500 MB), which I import as

```
sdlist = Import[
   "C:\\Users\\Debajyoti Sengupta\\Documents\\Processing\\collide_pde\
\\spatial_density.txt", "CSV"];
sdsplit = Select[SplitBy[sdlist, Length], Length[#] != 1 &];
```

Now I want to plot a SmoothDensityHistogram for each of the split datasets, and make a animated movie. The aim is to be able to export it.

I tried

```
ListAnimate[SmoothDensityHistogram /@ sdsplit]
```

But that doesn't let me control the binning and other aspects of my smoothdensityhistogram?

Is there any other way?

Comment: `ListAnimate[SmoothDensityHistogram[#,spec]& /@ sdsplit]`

Comment: Could you please explain what it does and how it helps me control the binning and other aspects and export the animation?

Comment: One way is `Show[{SmoothDensityHistogram[sdsplit[[1]],bin,spec],SmoothDensityHistogram[sdsplit[[2]],bin,spec],....}]` Now I can map the same plot set up for all `sdsplit` as above.

Comment: Do you want to use the same `bin` and `other aspects` for all `sdsplit`?

Comment: Yes, binning will be same for all the sdsplit.

Comment: Also, how do I export this animation as a movie?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ImportAndExportAnimations.html